# Reading an object from a file, than add to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, io, binary

Now i'm working on a school assignment for java binary I/O.

i have to write some Restaurant dishes, write those to a file. also i have to read these objects from the file.

for now i got it working that i write dishes to the file using this piece of code

```
private ArrayList<Gerecht> gerechten;

public void writeToFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    try {

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Menu.txt"));
        out.writeBytes(gerechten.toString());
    } // catch any file creation errors
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file: Menu.txt");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file: Menu.txt");

    }
}
```

An "Gerecht" Object contains:

A name = naam.

a Price = prijs.

Callories = calorien.

```
public abstract class Gerecht extends Menu{
private String naam;
private double prijs;
private int calorien;


public Gerecht(String naam, double prijs, int calorien) {
    this.naam = naam;
    this.prijs = prijs;
    this.calorien=calorien;


}
```

When i create an object with the constructor above i get this kind of output.

Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/37d8238aa8b35cb0da06e0d4fca10fa0

ignore the 4th line of all Dishes in the Arraylist, this has to do with super/subclasses.

now i have to read this output, and create objects of them. for example: i  would manualy type another dish in the file, with the same layout, there should be 4 objects instead of 3.

i know this post is long, but i have been stuck for a few days now!

Comment: I think you need to use the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream classes here for serialization, and deserialization, respectively.

Links => 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html AND http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

You either need:

1. **to parse the written string and manually create an object** or
2. **take advantage of object serialization**:

   ```
   try {
       ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Menu.txt"));
       out.writeObject(gerechten);
   } // catch any file creation errors
   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Error opening file: Menu.txt");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Error writing file: Menu.txt");
   }
   ```